# Figuring out where a file is in Windows PATH

Tags: windows, shell

How can I determine which file command is calling?  For example, when I call "python", I want to know that the system executes

C:/Python27/python.exe

(I'm working on Windows, if that makes a difference.)

Comment: What do you mean by "which file along the path"?

Comment: I want to know which file in the windows PATH the shell is executing.  (I edited the question for clarity - thanks for the comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WHERE` from a command line.  For your specific example: `where python.exe`